# Combine two separate 8.5 x 11 PDF documents into one 11 x 17 PDF document?

Tags: windows, macos, pdf, combine

I have some 8.5 x 11 PDF documents that are the "left" and "right" pages of what should be a 11 x 17 document.  I am looking for a way to combine/stitch these files together.  Either a Windows or Mac solution is acceptable.

Most solutions I find seem to merge these two single page documents into a two page document, and not combine them side by side into a 11 x 17 larger document.

Additionally, I'd prefer the solution to be "free" and "easy":  "Free" meaning I'd rather not buy a commercial product and "easy" meaning not having to download and compile a set of command line tools.

Comment: https://forums.adobe.com/message/3098742

Comment: When you have those two pages together (now as they became two columns of a bigger page), what are you going to do further (folding, stitching etc.)? Also, am I correct to assume that one document has the left pages, and one the right ones?

Answer (score 2):

1. Merge all pdf files  to single pdf file
2. you can achieve this scenario in Acrobat Pro/Reader 9
3. open your Pdf  file in Acrobat Pro/Reader 9
4. Press **ctrl+p** to open printing option
5. Use booklet option to merge pages as left and right side like
   ([1,2][3,4])
6. set the following parameter. Please note that name should Adobe pdf
   and not your printer
7. Once you got your file as booklet you can resize it as per your
   desire

[image]

Hope this helps!